# src/app/components/user.components.ts(37,14): error TS7006: Parameter 'i' implicitly has an 'any' type

Tags: angular

When running my app, I get the following errors:

> src/app/components/user.components.ts(33,11): error TS7006: Parameter 'Hobbi' implicitly has an 'any' type.
>   [0] src/app/components/user.components.ts(37,14): error TS7006: Parameter 'i' implicitly has an 'any' type.

Here is my code:

```
@Component({
  moduleId : module.id,
  selector: 'user',
  templateUrl: `user.components.html`,
})
export class UserComponent  { 
    name : string;
    email : String;
    address: address;
    hobbies : string[];
    ShowHobbies : boolean;
    constructor(){
        this.name = 'Ratheesh';
        this.email = 'babu.ratheesh@7nodes.com';
        this.address={
            street : 'Near Assisi Lane',
            city: 'Ernakulam',
            country : 'India'
        }
        this.hobbies = ['Reading', 'sports' , 'music']
        this.ShowHobbies = false;
    }
    ToggleHobbies(){
        // console.log('SHow');
        if(this.ShowHobbies == true) {
            this.ShowHobbies = false;
        }else{
            this.ShowHobbies = true;
        }
    }
    addHobby(Hobbi){
        this.hobbies.push(Hobbi);

    }
    deleteHobby(i){
        this.hobbies.splice(i, 1);

    }

}

interface address {
    street : string;
    city: string;
    country :string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the type as **`any`**,

```
 addHobby(Hobbi:any){
        this.hobbies.push(Hobbi);
 }
```